# Ontology-based knowledge graph construction from free-text

Tags: information-extraction, knowledge-graph

**TL;DR**

What is the best way to extract SPO triples from free-text with as little information loss as possible under the constraint that the nodes and relationships in the extracted triples are contained in a given ontology?

**Details**

I am trying to build a knowledge graph (KG) from free-text. As stated in [this paper by Nickel et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00759), open information extraction (openIE) techniques typically lead to very sparse adjencency tensors that are often difficult to use in down-stream applications. To avoid this issue, I would like the resulting KG to feature only nodes and relationships of specific, pre-defined types as given by an ontology.

**Question**

Assuming, such an ontology exists, what is the best way to extract as much information from the free-text as possible and align the triples with the ontology?

For me the naive way would be to go for a two-step approach where

1. I first perfom openIE and
2. then I classify the extracted nodes and edges into the classes given by the types in the ontology.

I am wondering if there is a (simpler) way that does not require the detour to do openIE first.

**Example:**
Let's start from the following free text.

"Thomas is Sarah's husband. She married him a couple of years ago. Together they have a little daughter, Michelle. Peter, an 8-year old boy, is Thomas's second child and Charlie is Peter's dog."

Let us assume that using openIE we would be able to extract a KG like this one:

[image: Sample knowledge graph as derived with openIE from the text above.]

However, let's further assume that our ontology only knows the following relationships:

- is_married_to
- is_child_of
- is_pet_of
- is_a

The desired output looks therefore as follows:

[image: Desired output KG after applying ontology]

**NOTICE:**
Notice that in this example the relationships "is_husband_of" was mapped to "is_married_to" and the relationship "has_daughter" is mapped to the relationship "is_child_of" (direction is inverted). I would like to avoid loss of information as a result of retaining only those relationships that happen to be aligned with the ontology. Explicitly, the KG below would not be an acceptable solution:

[image: Resulting KG with information loss (missing relationships) as only those relationships have been retained that happened to be in the ontology.]

Does anyone know any suitable algorithms or literature where such approaches are described?